# SQL Table highest sequence number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sequence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selecting the Highest Seq Number by nested Joining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320407/selecting-the-highest-seq-number-by-nested-joining)

Hello I have to write a query , I would like to take biggest sequence number for each client Id (big sequence number will be calculated based on highest bank account balance).

Please consider this table has 100000records.

table is like as below-

Table:

```
  
**ClID**      **SeqNu**     **Bal**  
1                 1              30000  
1                 2              26789  
1                 3              23456  
1                 4              12345  
1                 5              21234  
2                 3              12456  
2                 4              45632  
2                 1              23456  
2                 9              99999  
3                 4              12345  
3                 5              21234  
3                 3              12456  
3                 4              45632
```

Result would be

```
**ClID**      **SeqNu**         **Bal**  
1                 1              30000  
2                 9              99999  
3                 4              45632
```

Comment: This might have been my editing... but I think you're right

Comment: It sounds like you want the highest `Bal`, not `SeqNu` - is your question title correct?

Comment: RedFileter, I Need Highest Number for the client(based on highest balance to that client id)

Comment: A tip: if you provide details as to your database platform, you will likely get better SQL in the answers.

Comment: @satish all the columns are numbers, highest number of what? Please use column names when discussing your business problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this will probably vary depending on which RDBMS you're using. If you have windowing functions (Oracle 9i+ or SQL Server 2012, for instance), the following should work:

```
select distinct ClId, 
                first_value(SeqNu) 
                    over (partition by ClId 
                          order by Bal desc) as SeqNu, 
                max(Bal) 
                    over (partition by ClId) as Bal
from your_table
```

Comment: @Allan- looks, something reasonable, let me try this.

Comment: @Allen, Hha Yes, I can't use this above query as am working on 2008r2. But as per your query logic I might reach my requirement. Is there any other way to acheive my issue?  Thank You.

Comment: If you can't use windowing functions, @RedFilter's answer is the best approach. Be sure to select it as the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
select t.*
from (
    select CIID,
        MAX(Bal) as MaxBalance
    from table
    group by CIID
    ) sm
inner join table t on sm.CIID = t.CIID and sm.MaxBalance = t.Bal
```

[SQL Fiddle example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa1b4/7)

Comment: If we do this way, again table t has different sequenceId, automately all the sequencesID's will come up in to the result. we can't filter the highest sequnce ID.  Please consider Max balance might be same for any other client and sequnceID combinations out 1000000records. We can't give a chance to wrong results. Thank You!

Comment: The JOIN clause is on CIID as well as MaxBalance, so no, you will not get duplicates of other CIIDs for the same MaxBalance. You may get duplicates for the same CIID and MaxBalance though, if that balance occurs more than once for the same CIID. You did not specify how to choose which SeqNo to return in that case so I am returning both. More detail from you = better answers from us.

Comment: @satish: This query is not using the highest sequence ID. It's getting the highest balance for each client ID, then using those values to find the correct sequence ID. Based on my reading of your question, this answer is correct.

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer :), props for the Fiddle :D

Comment: @satish I added a SQLFiddle example showing output that matches yours. If you have case it does not work for, please update your data sample and desired output.

Comment: props to @Jake Feasel for creating SQL Fiddle, I just learned he is a SO participant

Comment: @RedFilter, You SQL Fiddle Is answer. Thank You!

Comment: Thanks @RedFilter - I'm glad people are finding it useful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT SeqNu, MAX(Bal)
FROM Table
GROUP BY SeqNu
```

Comment: This is entirely wrong. The poster wanted the `SeqNu` associated with the highest `Bal` within each group of `ClId`. This gives the highest `Bal` within each `SeqNu`.

Comment: @Allan - The question has been edited, from the original post I believe it only included SeqNu and Bal, hence my answer.

Comment: @DarrenDavies If you go back and look at the original question, you can see there were always 3 columns in the output, just one column title was missing...

Comment: @RedFilter the output isn't even the same, I tested his code on your fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two nested `MAX` statements to match it all up:

```
SELECT a.ClID, MAX(b.SeqNu) as SeqNu, b.Balance
FROM Table a
JOIN (SELECT ClID, MAX(Balance) as Balance FROM Table GROUP BY ClID) b 
   ON a.ClID = b.ClID AND a.Balance = b.Balance 
GROUP BY a.ClID, b.SeqNu
```

Comment: Hi cjk, In your nested query we are taking max of seuquence number for the clientId, then in the main query we assiging the balance for that. I don't this works for the case  3                 4              45632

Comment: I've reversed the MAX which should now work...

Comment: cjk, If there are any duplicate records in sequnce number, then your max(seq) works, we have to take sequnce number based on max(balance). Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b1.*
FROM balance b1
LEFT JOIN balance b2
ON (b1.clid = b2.clid AND b2.bal > b1.bal)
WHERE b2.clid IS NULL;

+------+-------+-------+
| clid | seqnu | bal   |
+------+-------+-------+
|    1 |     1 | 30000 |
|    2 |     9 | 99999 |
|    3 |     4 | 45632 |
+------+-------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```