# first_value' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql-server

Hello Am trying my query as belo.
Please see the two different versions of query and its error message.

```
SELECT first_value(col1) AS 'inv',col2 
FROM dbo.table  
--first_value' is not a recognized built-in function name.  

SELECT dbo.first_value(col1) AS 'inv',col2 
FROM dbo.table  
--Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.first", or the name is ambiguous.

SELECT first_value(col1) AS 'inv',col2 
FROM dbo.table 
GROUP BY col2  
--'first' is not a recognized built-in function name.

SELECT dbo.first_value(col1) AS 'inv',col2 
FROM dbo.table 
GROUP BY col2  
--Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.first", or the name is ambiguous.
```

Please any help!

Comment: And what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: is first_value a function that you are trying to access?

Comment: Am trying to use First_value and First function, just for sample test before inserting into main query. resulted error messages are as above!

Comment: unless you have created a function called first_value or first, sql server doesn't have those functions. can you clearly explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Did you create the function with a different user than dbo?

Comment: FIRST_VALUE is a new Analytical function SQL Server 2012 and your SQL syntax is completely wrong if that is what you are attempting to use, if of course you are even using SQL Server 2012. See MSDN for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx

Comment: No no, I checked all. Yes I found first and First_value functions are not in my db. How i need to get them into my db?

Comment: @creamyegg,  hmm your right, am using 2008r2. Is there any way to overcome on this issue? I would like to acheive main query                   select distinct ClId, first_value(SeqNu) over (partition by ClId order by Bal desc) as SeqNu, max(Bal) over (partition by ClId) as Bal from your_table

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to pull the top / first record from a table, you need to specify the criteria by which a row is defined as the first / top row

```
SELECT top 1  col1 AS inv,col2  
FROM dbo.table 
ORDER BY col1 --or whatever criteria you need here
```

first_value as far as I can tell seems to be a MS SQL Server 2012 function, which also requires an ordering clause - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx

Comment: hmm your right, am using 2008r2. Is there any way to overcome on this issue? I would like to acheive main query select distinct ClId,                  first_value(SeqNu)                      over (partition by ClId                            order by Bal desc) as SeqNu,                  max(Bal)                      over (partition by ClId) as Bal from your_table

Comment: So are you trying to get the first SeqNu for each Clld ordering by Bal? If so, do you only want one row per Clld?

Comment: Please we can continue in another thread. for this issu. I understand as am using 2008R2 I can't use the above query! Please find the allen-Satish discussion on my business logic query at fallowing thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317027/sql-table-highest-sequence-number/10317111#comment13281422_10317111