# Selecting the Highest Seq Number by nested Joining

Tags: sql-server

I would like to take biggest sequence number for each client Id (biggest sequence number will be calculated based on highest bank account balance).

This table has 100000 records.

Tables

ClientSeqTable  T1

```
ClID              SeqId     
1                 11         
1                 12         
1                 13         
1                 14         
1                 15         
2                 16         
2                 17         
2                 18         
2                 19         
3                 110         
3                 111         
3                 112         
3                 113
```

SeqBranchTable T2

```
SeqId    BalID  
11         1  
12         2  
13         3  
14         4  
15         5  
16         6  
17         7  
18         8  
19         9  
110         10  
111         11  
112         12  
113         13
```

Balancetable t3

```
BalID Balance  
1     30000  
2     26789  
3     23456  
4     12345  
5     21234  
6     12456  
7     45632  
8     23456  
9     99999  
10    12345  
11    21234  
12    12456  
13    45632
```

Result would be

```
ClID              SeqID          Balance  
1                 1              30000  
2                 9              99999  
3                 4              45632
```

I have tried in this way but didn't work for me

```
SELECT  RS.Investigationid,MAX(stt.sequenceid) 'SeqId', T.HighestBalance 'Balance' 
FROM    ClientSeqTable  T1, SeqBranchTable T2, branbaltable t3,  
                ( SELECT    t1.clid ,MAX(T3.Balance) 'HighestBalance'
                    FROM    ClientSeqTable  T1, SeqBranchTable T2, branbaltable t3,
                    WHERE   t1.seqid =  T2.seqID
                    AND     T2. balId= T3. balId
                    GROUP BY  RS.Investigationid,stt.SequenceId
                    ) T
WHERE   T2.balId =  T3.BalId
AND T1.SeqId = T2.SeqId
AND     T3.HighestBalance = T2.balance
AND     T1.clID = t.ClID
GROUP BY  T1.ClID
```

With the above Query results are as below.

```
ClID            SeqNu          Bal    
1               1              30000    
1               2              30000  
1               3              30000  
1               4              30000  
1               5              30000  
2               3              99999    
2               4              99999    
2               1              99999    
2               9              99999    
3               2              45632  
3               5              45632  
3               3              45632  
3               4              45632
```

Comment: Your example query doesn't match the data examples e.g. is shown T1.SeqId is shown in your query but not in your data example!

Comment: How does T1 relate to T2 and how does T2 relate to T3?

Comment: t1.seqid =  T2.seqID  & T2. branchId= T3. branchId

Comment: I presume SeqNu is SeqId in your data example?

Comment: @Siva, Please find the updated data.

Comment: @Siva, Thanks for your attention, Please see below Mouters Answer for the above question.Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your able to use row_number function then should work:

```
select 
    *
from 
(
    select 
        t1.ClID, t1.SeqId, t3.Bal, 
        RowNumber = row_number() over (PARTITION BY t1.ClID order by t3.bal desc)
    from 
        ClientSeqTable t1
    inner join
        SeqBranchTable t2 on t2.SeqId = t1.SeqId
    inner join
        Balancetable t3 on t3.BalID = t2.BalID
) t
where
    t.RowNumber = 1
```

The important bit is row number partition by client id and then order by balance descending.

Comment: @@@@Mouters, I don't have proper reputations to give 10000's of points to you. At this moment I would like to say, Thank you Very Much! You are the man, Who made my day!

Comment: No problem, I seem to be using row number more and more to simplify queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get your In-line on MAX you could do it this way

```
SELECT t1.ClID, 
       t1.SeqId, 
       t3.Balance 
FROM   ClientSeqTable t1 
       INNER JOIN SeqBranchTable t2 
         ON t2.SeqId = t1.SeqId 
       INNER JOIN Balancetable t3 
         ON t3.BalID = t2.BalID 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(Balance) Bal, 
                          t1.ClID 
                   FROM   ClientSeqTable t1 
                          INNER JOIN SeqBranchTable t2 
                            ON t2.SeqId = t1.SeqId 
                          INNER JOIN Balancetable t3 
                            ON t3.BalID = t2.BalID 
                   GROUP  BY t1.ClID) max_bal 
         ON t1.ClID = max_bal.ClID 
            AND t3.Balance = max_bal.bal
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b974/18)

But you should note this is not actually equivalent to using row_number ([mouters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10321152/119477) solution). This may return multiple rows per ClID if there's a tie for max(balance). If you need that way of handling ties and you wanted to use a window function [you could use RANK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b974/22).